# How to call variadic template function with defined first parameter through std::apply?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm relatively new to parameter packs, but I want to build a class that receives argument pack, collects values that are contained within and launches them into another function.

I have a class that has variadic template and a function which assigns values. Function is taking arguments from VARIANT structure.

**Unwrapper Function:**

```
 template <typename...Args>
    constexpr void ValuesFromValuesVariant(VARIANT variant, Args&...args)
    {
        static std::size_t nArgs = sizeof...(Args);
        if (!nArgs) return;
        auto vArray = GetArray(variant, nArgs);

        auto i = 0u;
        GetNextItem(vArray, i, args);
    }
```

**Class that uses it:**

```
template <class ...Args>
class Receiver
{
    using SendFunction = std::function<HRESULT(Args...)>;
    using InterruptFunc = std::function<HRESULT()>;
    ...
    virtual HRESULT OnSend(VARIANT params)
    {
        //Here I'd like to call it with a VARIANT, but I can't for some reason
        std::apply(ValuesFromValuesVariant, params, std::tie(arguments)); //std::tie to get refs& to the arguments

        HRESULT hr = std::apply(m_Function, arguments);
        return hr;
    }
private:
    InterruptFunc m_InterruptFunc;
    SendFunction m_Function;
private:
    std::tuple< Args... > arguments;
};
```

I've tried to std::bind a first function parameter, but it can't automatically predict what arguments it's taking, 
`VariantCommunication::ValuesFromValuesVariant<Args>` specifier does not work.

Comment: not think that *winapi* here somehow related

Comment: @RbMm I see `HRESULT`s and `VARIANT`s, isn't it [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-variant) thing? I can't find what `GetArray` and `GetNextItem` are though.

Comment: @Quentin - if say replace `HRESULT` to `int` the essence of the question will not change. i think that this is pure c++ question

Comment: @RbMm but what about `VARIANT` and the associated functions?

Comment: @Quentin `GetArray` and `GetNextItem` not well known functions. this is not part of winapi. only OP can know - what is this custom function. `VARIANT` - yes, windows structure, but if replace it on any c++ struct - are question and answer will change ?

Comment: @RbMm well yeah, since the end goal AFAICT is to call `GetArray` and `GetNextItem` properly. But if you're positive that this is not Microsoft's `VARIANT` and functions I'll just remove the tag of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `apply` with extra arguments than tuple, you might capture it in the functor:

```
std::apply([&](auto&... args){ ValuesFromValuesVariant(params, args...); }, arguments);
```

or concat extra parameter to the tuple:

```
std::apply(&ValuesFromValuesVariant, std::tuple_cat(std::tie(params), arguments));
```

Answer (score 2):

First, `std::tie(arguments)` does not create a `std::tuple` of references to the elements of `arguments`.  What it will do is create a `std::tuple` that has single element which is a reference to `arguments`.  To get a tuple of references to a tuple need an adapter like

```
template<typename... Elems, std::size_t... Indicies>
auto make_reference_tuple_impl(std::tuple<Elems...>& tuple, std::index_sequence<Indicies...> indices)
{
    return std::tuple<Elems&...>{std::get<Indicies>(tuple)...};
}

template<typename... Elems>
auto make_reference_tuple(std::tuple<Elems...>& tuple)
{
    return make_reference_tuple_impl(tuple, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Elems)>{});
}
```

and then what you need to do is turn `params` into a tuple of a reference as well with `std::tie` and then you can combine those tuple together with [`std::tuple_cat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat).  You also need to wrap `ValuesFromValuesVariant` in a lambda since you can pass a function template to `std::apply`.  Putting all that together will give you code that will look like

```
virtual HRESULT OnSend(VARIANT params)
{
    auto param_ref = std::tie(params);
    auto arg_ref = make_reference_tuple(arguments);
    auto concat = std::tuple_cat(param_ref, arg_ref);
    std::apply([](auto...& args){ValuesFromValuesVariant(args);}, concat);

    HRESULT hr = std::apply(m_Function, arguments);
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: VARIANT is not needed to be passed as reference, and won't 
`std::apply([](auto...& args){ValuesFromValuesVariant(args);}, concat);`
turn concat into references to references?

Comment: @IlyaPakhmutov I used `std::tie` so that `params` doesn't get copied.  I wasn't sure what it was but if it can't/shouldn't be copied then you're safe with this.  It wont turn concat into a reference of references.  What it does it give you references to what `param_ref` and `arg_ref` refer to.

Comment: would it not be easier then to capture values by references? like `[&] (auto&...args)` ...

Comment: @IlyaPakhmutov It would.  That is exactly what Jarod42 did in their answer and I up voted it since it was a better approach.  C++ gives you many ways to skin a cat and I got caught up in all the tuples and forgot I could just capture `params`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `ValuesFromValuesVariant` takes its parameters by Lvalue reference, first you need to create tuple of Lvalue references from `arguments`. Then you can use `tuple_cat` to concatenate tuple created from `params` and the previous one:

It may look like:

```
virtual HRESULT OnSend(VARIANT params)
{
    // [1] make tuple of references to arguments
    auto makeRef = [](auto & ... args){ return std::forward_as_tuple(args...); };
    auto t1 = std::apply( makeRef , arguments);

    // [2] make tuple from params
    auto t2 = std::forward_as_tuple(params);
    std::apply(ValuesFromValuesVariant<Args...>, std::tuple_cat( t1, t2 ) );

    HRESULT hr{1};
    return hr;
}
```

[Here is minimal demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1DYcXS)